# Inserting Data Into MySQL Database Using PHP Gets An Error

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to insert data from a HTML form and PHP script to a MySQL Database.

I am able to connect to the MySQL server from the script but I cannot connect to the Database and table. So that I cannot insert data.

The error that triggers from the PHP script. The error is 'Database is not selected !'. But I have declared the name correctly.

Here I have uploaded the [full solution](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7Hii9aqsRAkZkxJTDJrc0NqU28/view?usp=sharing) .

Below I have added the HTML form and the PHP Script.

Could you please try to solve the issue if possible.

***HTML Form***

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Registration Form</title>
</head>
<body>
    <br />
    <h2 align="center">Register a new customer</h2>
    <h3 align="center">Fill all fields</h3>
    <form action="insertdata.php" method="post">
        <table align="center">
            <tr>
                <td>First Name:</td>
                <td><input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Middle Name:</td>
                <td><input type="text" id="mname" name="mname" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Last Name:</td>
                <td><input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>NIC / Driving License No:</td>
                <td><input type="text" id="NICNo" name="nicno" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Permanent Address Name:</td>
                <td><input type="text" id="paddress" name="paddress" /></td>
            </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>E-Mail Address:</td>
                <td><input type="text" id="email" name="email" /></td>
            </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>Telephone:</td>
                <td><input type="text" id="telno" name="telno" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Mobile No:</td>
                <td><input type="text" id="mobileno" name="mobileno" /></td>
            </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>Date of Registration:</td>
                <td><input type="text" id="regdate" name="regdate" /></td>
            </tr>
                <tr><td></td></tr>
                <tr><td></td></tr>
                <tr><td></td></tr>
                <tr><td></td></tr>
                <tr><td></td></tr>
                <tr><td></td></tr>
            <tr>
            <td align="center"><input type="submit" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;  <input type="reset" /></td>

            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>

  </body>
```

***InsertData.php***

```
    <?php

     $dbserver = 'localhost';
     $username = 'root';
     $password = '';

     $dbname = 'car_rental';

     $con = mysqli_connect($dbserver, $username, $password);

     if(!$con)
 {
     echo "Not connected to server !";
     echo 'ERROR : '.mysql_error();

 }else{
     echo "Server connected !";
 }

    if(!mysqli_select_db($con, $dbname));
   {
      echo "Database not selected !";
      echo 'ERROR : '.mysql_error();
  }

   $fname = $_POST["fname"];
   $mname = $_POST["mname"];
   $lname = $_POST["lname"];
   $nicno = $_POST["nicno"];
   $paddress = $_POST["paddress"];
   $email = $_POST["email"];
   $telno = $_POST["telno"];
   $mobileno = $_POST["mobileno"];
   $regdate = $_POST["regdate"];

   $sql = "INSERT INTO new_customers (FirstName, MiddleName, LastName, NICNo, PermanentAddress, EmailAddress, Telephone, Mobile, RegDate) VALUES ('$fname','$mname','$lname','$nicno','$paddress','$email','$telno','$mobileno','$regdate')";

 if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
       echo "Data not inserted !";
       echo 'ERROR : '.mysql_error();
  }
  else
  {
     echo "Data inserted !";
  }

   header("refresh:300; url=form.php");

  ?>
```

Comment: you can use mysqli OOPS concept Example: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php

Comment: 1. Fix your error detection to not use the outdated and deprecated `mysql_...()` functions, stick with the `mysqli_:::()` functions.

Comment: 2. Check your http servers error log file to see what is actually happening.

Comment: 3. Find out about the advantages of using "prepared statements" in combination with "parameter binding". Your current code is _wide open_ to sql injection attacks.

Comment: So what is the wrong statement of the solution then. Because none of the suggestions are not helping me :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

> `mysqli_connect($dbserver, $username, $password, $dbname);`

Answer (score 0):

try this

> $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=[databasename]', 'root', '');

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<?php

$dbserver = 'localhost';
$username = 'root';
$password = '';
$dbname = 'car_rental';

$con = mysqli_connect($dbserver, $username, $password);

if(!$con) {
    echo "Not connected to server !";
    echo 'ERROR : '.mysqli_error($con);
} else {
    echo "Server connected !";
}

if(!mysqli_select_db($con, $dbname)) {
    echo "Database not selected !";
    echo 'ERROR : '.mysqli_error($con);
}

$fname = $_POST["fname"];
$mname = $_POST["mname"];
$lname = $_POST["lname"];
$nicno = $_POST["nicno"];
$paddress = $_POST["paddress"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$telno = $_POST["telno"];
$mobileno = $_POST["mobileno"];
$regdate = $_POST["regdate"];

$sql = "INSERT INTO new_customers (FirstName, MiddleName, LastName, NICNo, PermanentAddress, EmailAddress, Telephone, Mobile, RegDate) VALUES ('$fname','$mname','$lname','$nicno','$paddress','$email','$telno','$mobileno','$regdate')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
    echo "Data not inserted !";
    echo 'ERROR : '.mysqli_error($con);
} else {
    echo "Data inserted !";
}

header("refresh:300; url=form.php");

?>
```

I haven't tested it.